# How to authenticate against AAD (Azure Active Directory) with oauth2_proxy and obtain Access Token

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-active-directory, oauth2-proxy

I'm trying to authenticate against AAD (Azure Active Directory) with [oauth2_proxy](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/) used in Kubernetes to obtain Access Token.

First of all, I'm struggling to get the correct authentication flow to work.

Second, after being redirected to my application, Access Token is not in the request headers specified in [oauth2_proxy](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/features/endpoints) documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some input on authentication against Azure Active Directory (AAD) using [oauth2_proxy](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/configuration/overview) in kubernetes.

First you need to create an application in AAD and add it `email`, `profile` and `User.Read` permissions to Microsoft Graph.

The default behavior of authentication flow, is that after login against Microsoft authentication server, you will be redirected to root of website with authentication code (e.g. `https://exampler.com/`). You would expect the Access Token to be visible there -this is a faulty assumption. The url that Access Token is injected into is `https://exampler.com/oauth2` !!!

Successful configuration of oauth2_proxt that worked is below.

**oauth2-proxy.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: oa2p
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --provider=oidc
        - --azure-tenant=88888888-aaaa-bbbb-cccc-121212121212
        - --email-domain=example.com
        - --http-address=0.0.0.0:4180
        - --set-authorization-header=true
        - --set-xauthrequest=true
        - --pass-access-token=true
        - --pass-authorization-header=true
        - --pass-user-headers=true
        - --pass-host-header=true
        - --skip-jwt-bearer-tokens=true
        - --oidc-issuer-url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/88888888-aaaa-bbbb-cccc-121212121212/v2.0
        env:
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: oauth2-proxy-secret
              key: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: oauth2-proxy-secret
              key: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: oauth2-proxy-secret
              key: OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET
        image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:v7.1.3
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: oauth2-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4180
          protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: oa2p
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 4180
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4180
  selector:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
```

**ingress.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oa2p
  namespace: oa2p
  annotations:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: "1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: "X-Auth-Request-Email,X-Auth-Request-Preferred-Username"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - oa2p.example.com
    secretName: oa2p-tls
  rules:
    - host: oa2p.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: oa2p
                port:
                  number: 8080
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oa2p-proxy
  namespace: oa2p
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: "1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "8k"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - oa2p.example.com
    secretName: oa2p-tls
  rules:
    - host: oa2p.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /oauth2
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: oauth2-proxy
                port:
                  number: 4180
```